# How do we add/implement HTTP/3 protocol to our web application?

Tags: http, tcp, udp, http2, http3

Actually we are working with protocol upgrade from HTTP/1.1 to HTTP/2. But heard about HTTP/3 got released. So that how do we add/implement HTTP/3 protocol to our web application?

Comment: There is no HTTP/3 yet. It is just the proposal to rename HTTP over QUIC to HTTP/3. It is not yet fully standardized and there is no support in common web servers for this yet. Chrome kind of uses it since it uses QUIC.

Comment: Usually, the business web site doesn't care about HTTP details, and only about requests/responses. The big change would happen in the web server, web client and any HTTP libraries you happen to use. Most likely, your only adaptation would be to upgrade all those when time comes, leaving the rest alone.

Answer (score 1):

QUIC has not been approved yet. Target date has been pushed back to July 2019. Implementations May take time to appear after this.